# npm run test @nrwl/angular: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nrwl-nx

If you got following message when run test in angular:

```
It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI
```

Conditions:

```
"@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/elements": "^10.0.4",
"@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/localize": "^10.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
"@nrwl/angular": "10.0.2",
"ngx-build-plus": "^10.1.1",
```

Answer (score 5):

To solve this issue, only add in test-settup.ts:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import '@angular/localize/init';
```